# How to select value from the drop down list (Selenium C#)

Tags: c#, html, select, selenium, element

I need an assistance, how can I select a value from a drop down list, I am programming on `C#` with `Selenium`, and I am always getting the following error:

> *Element should have been select but was span*

My code is:

```
internal static void SelectDD()
{
    SelectElement xxx= new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[1]/section/div[1]/div[2]/section/div/section/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/a/span[1]")));

    xxx.SelectByIndex(1);
}
```

HTML:

```
<span class="select2-hidden-accessible" role="status" aria-live="polite"></span> <span class="select2-hidden-accessible" role="status" aria-live="polite"></span> <span class="select2-hidden-accessible" role="status" aria-live="polite"></span> 
<div id="select2-drop-mask" class="select2-drop-mask" style="display: block;"></div>
<div id="select2-drop" class="select2-drop select2-display-none select2-drop-auto-width select2-drop-active select2-drop-above" style="left: 361.583px; top: 472.1px; bottom: auto; display: block; width: 262px;"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: HTML:

<span class="select2-hidden-accessible" role="status" aria-live="polite"></span>

<span class="select2-hidden-accessible" role="status" aria-live="polite"></span>

<span class="select2-hidden-accessible" role="status" aria-live="polite"></span>

<div id="select2-drop-mask" class="select2-drop-mask" style="display: block;"></div>

***<div id="select2-drop" class="select2-drop select2-display-none select2-drop-auto-width select2-drop-active select2-drop-above" style="left: 361.583px; top: 472.1px; bottom: auto; display: block; width: 262px;"></div>***

</body>

Comment: you have to edit your question and put code inside that.

Comment: @NoamIgorVeronin Are those hidden?

Comment: Select2 styles the dropdown in a way to hide the underlying `select`. Why on earth is your method an `internal static` method?

Comment: Yep there are hidden

Answer (score 2):

First of all `SelectElement` can only be used with the element with `Select` tag. This is a `div` and `SelectElement` class does not apply here.

Try finding the element and just performing a click as follows:

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("select2-drop"));

IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Comment: Thanks for the advise but actually its still doesn't select the value from the DD, the element located successfully and the drop down list opened but the value doesn't selected.

Comment: This is what you mean?

Comment: What value you are talking about?

Comment: I mean when I ran the test , I was able to open the drop down list but no value was selected from this dropdown

Comment: The `div` with `select2-drop` is the one you want to select?

Comment: Can you provide me more `html` then? Including the parent of the dropdown

Comment: Hi you can find below extended HTML and My code:  public static void SelectDD()
       {
           IWebElement xxx = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[1]/section/div[1]/div[2]/section/div/section/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/a/span[1]"));
           xxx.Click();

           IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[5]/ul/li[3]/div"));
           IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
           js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
       }

Comment: <span class="select2-hidden-accessible" role="status" aria-live="polite"></span>

<span class="select2-hidden-accessible" role="status" aria-live="polite"></span>

<span class="select2-hidden-accessible" role="status" aria-live="polite"></span>

<div id="select2-drop-mask" class="select2-drop-mask" style="display: block;"></div>

<div id="select2-drop" class="select2-drop select2-display-none select2-drop-auto-width select2-drop-active select2-drop-above" style="left: 363.583px; top: 472.1px; bottom: auto; display: block; width: 262px;"></div>

Comment: The part that I need to on the HTML is:                                                               <div id="select2-drop-mask" class="select2-drop-mask" style="display: block;"></div>

Comment: This is not the element selector I provided you. Have you tried that? And, use id instead of xpath. You have ids `select2-drop-mask`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the dropdown is not actually a drop down. Select Element can only work with  element the html should be like below.

A work around would be to create a custom method which will suit the html structure you have now.

```
var spans = driver.FindElements({selector});

foreach(var span in spans)
{
   if(span.Text == "some")
     span.Click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the text of the DropDown, you can use method SendKeys(string text) of IWebElement

```
internal static void SelectDD()
{
     IWebElement xxx= driver.FindElement("");
     xxx.SendKeys("Text Of The Dropdown");
}
```